# Scala functional programming and mutability

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Pet(name: String) {
  def getName: String = {
    name match {
      case "" => generateRandomName
      case _  => name
    }
  }
}

object Pet {
  def apply(name: String) = new Pet(name)
}
```

where creating a `Pet` with an empty name would create a `Pet` with a random name. How would I save the state of the newly generated random name, so calling this method twice would return the same name generated from the first call?

```
val pet = Pet("")

// Let's say this prints "bob"
println(pet.getName)

// I want this to still print "bob". This would generate a new random name because the state isn't saved from the previous call. 
println(pet.getName)
```

I'd like to avoid `var` because it's considered bad practice -- how do you go about doing something like this? Is the best way to create a new copy of the class? That doesn't seem very efficient to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a default value in the constructor, you can do something like this...

```
class Pet(name: String = generateRandomName) {
  def getName: String = name
}
```

Then when you do this...

```
val pet = new Pet()
```

...`getName` will always return the same generated name, but this...

```
val pet = new Pet("")
```

...will populate `name` as an empty `String`.